# How to get a div of such form that works in all browsers (IE10+)?

Tags: javascript, css, css-shapes

I am facing an issue with the div element of such form:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get this shape? Ideally, the solution should work at least in IE10+. Thanks in advance.

Do not suggest to split images. I am aware of this. Triangles on both sides must be transparent.

**BIG BIG EDIT**

[image]

This is what should be avoided. Grey background should stay uncovered.

Comment: You could achieve this with `before` and `after` pseudo elements.

Comment: what you've you tried so far?

Comment: Yep, I am aware of this. That was the first idea in fact. I am searching for more elegant solution. Probably with transformations. @NiZa

Comment: @dippas I did what NiZa mentioned. I will edit the question

Comment: Google 'triangle divs css' - create two of them, one absolute left, one absolute right, with the background-color set to match the outside, inside your main element. Make the background of your main element your image above.

Comment: The triange should be transparent, isn't it? Then its hard to achieve this with those pseudo elements..

Comment: @NiZa yesssss! That is what I am talking about

Comment: Not necessarily, triangle divs can have colour. Place them **left** and **right** of a square with the background image showing behind. This gives the **illusion** of having triangles with a background on the **top** and **bottom**

Comment: @Lewis hey, thanks, probably you can post an answer to clarify this?

Comment: @NiZa can you propose something?

Comment: You could also make the shape as a SVG and cut it out that way.

Comment: mix-blend-mode could be an option some days http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyEMyB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure both browser compatibility AND a gradient/image background, you may find you will have to use multiple elements, as well as a pseudo element on each of the nested divs. A quick mock up can be seen below.

```css
html {
  background: radial-gradient(red, black);
}
div.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  
  margin: 50px auto;  /*demo only*/
}
div.part1,
div.part2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 71%;
  width: 71%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.part1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-position: 0 -300px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
div.part2 {
  top: -50%;
}
div.part2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-position: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="part1"></div>
  <div class="part2"></div>
</div>
```

<sup>Please note the background position may require altering to ensure the final image is 'in sync' with each other.</sup>

Comment: Initially, I didn't want to approach it this way, but it looks like there are no alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: For your requirements, either this on possibly and SVG approach would be of the few ways of achieving this.

Comment: Yes, I considered SVG but I have many different of these. Such an overhead. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  background-image: url('http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the-simpsons.jpg');
  background-size: 400px 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  content: '';
}

div:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  background-position: 0 0;
}

div:after {
  top: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I had no idea this was possible.

Comment: @Lewis Yay, look how I received 6 down votes, but you have learned something new. That's nice!

Comment: @Nize IE does not support clip path(

Comment: Don't be disheartened by downvotes - 9/10 times, they aren't from the question itself, but from how the question is presented. I actually upvoted you, but was probably incorrect to do so. You didn't provide a clear demonstration of how you tried to solve this problem yourself and your question was difficult to understand. It seems to depend on the community's mood on a day to day basis. Imo, learning something > reputation.

Comment: There's very little [support for clip path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) I'm afraid.

Comment: @jbutler483 You are right, hmm too bad. Then he you should use your answer :)

Comment: @Niza you misunderstood me, ie8 supports simple clip but not clip path with exotic shapes

Comment: Good solution. The browser support (or lack of it) is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Try Coloured CSS triangles, absolutely positioned to the left and right of a square to give the illusion of transparent triangles on the top and bottom.

Demo JS fiddle here

> https://jsfiddle.net/32w08myL/

### HTML

```
<div id="square">
  <div class="triangle-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle-right"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#square{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://unseenflirtspoetry.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/homer-excited.png");
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle-left{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
  border-left: 200px solid #f3f5f6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

.triangle-right{
  width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 200px solid transparent; 
    border-right:200px solid #f3f5f6; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Triangles should be transparent!

Comment: @efimovD What do you mean 'transparent'? This looks exactly like the example you posted?

Comment: @efimovD Never mind, I understand what you mean. This wouldn't work for that I suppose.

Comment: By transparent I mean "transparent" or alpha = 0 or whatsoever, I believe you got me right. Change the color of this triangle and you will understand that it covers grey background but it shouldn't. The solution therefore is not universal.

Comment: So essentially, if there is something behind the triangles, say, another image or text, you want to be able to see it, while maintaining the cut-out shape? @NiZa probably does have the best answer for this.